# How to pack an extracted initrd (x-cpio archive)?

Tags: linux, initrd

I am customizing an Ubuntu 20.04 ISO, in this process, I have to edit the files inside `initrd` file which is inside the `casper` directory `Ubuntu20.04-ISO/casper/initrd`

How to recompile this file type of CPIO-archive (application/x-cpio)

[image]
[image]

I am able to unpack its contents with below command.

```
unmkinitramfs initrd .
```

But I am not able to recompile it, How can I Achieve this?

Looking for a practical step by step answer, I mean copy pasting the `initrd` file to new directory and recompiling it and proven to boot with this newly created say `myinitrd` file.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Usually you would pack an initramfs with `find . | cpio -oH | gzip > ../newinitramfs` but there can be more than 1 archive in a given file.

Comment: The  option `-H` requires an arguent (the archive type), where is this from? BTW: You could run `star -t -print-artype < archive` to find the archive type of the original archive.

Comment: That comment is wrong. The problem with `cpio` is that there is no `cpio` archive format, but 4 distinct and incompatible formats. You need to know which format to create to be compatible.

Comment: my goal is simle.. I have `initrd` file. I can extract the contents of it with the said command. I want to create a new initrd file with those extracted files.

Comment: You should install `star`.  It is the oldest free `tar` implementation. Much older than the `gtar` clone implementation found on most linux distros.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, since you need to use the same path names as in the original. You need to start with listing the original and then use the same path names for the copy. BTW: on user friendly Linux distros, `cpio` is a link to `star`

Comment: @schily the `initrd` file is from the downloaded iso. releases.ubuntu.com/20.04. I have uploaded it via wetransfer.. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/dec52f09867e7b6c56dd5804cbd8b38120200601130644/e3145e

Comment: @schily once I mounted the downloaded ISO. this is the file https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2NWq.png

Answer (score 8):

Depending on the targeted device/config `initrd` may have different format, you can check its format with:

```
binwalk ./initrd
```

According to your cross posts the required format for your initrd is `cpio` formatted with `newc` along with `lzma` compression, and thus a method of identification would be the following... **note that this is just to explain how to identify an initrd**:

```
binwalk initrd

#DECIMAL    HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
#------------------------------------------
# 0         0x0             LZMA compressed data

cp initrd compressedinit.xz
xz -d compressedinit.xz
binwalk compressedinit

#DECIMAL    HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
#------------------------------------------
# 0         0x0             ASCII cpio archive...
# 112       0x70            ASCII cpio archive...
# ...
```

This permit to identify the `initrd` as `cpio` formatted with `newc` along with `lzma` compression. Packing/Repacking an `initrd` depend on it's format. With `binwalk`, `xz`, `gzip` etc. you should be able to discover the used format and thus recreate it after extraction according to the used compression.

Note that `cpio` `-H` option determine the archive format, this can be one of the following `crc newc odc bin ustar tar` depending on the targeted format.

As your extracted `initrd` contains:

```
~/test$ ls
early  early2  main
```

You can use the following steps to unpack and repack it (source: your superuser's [QA](https://superuser.com/questions/1556241/initrd-file-cpio-archive-x-cpio-type-of-file-how-to-recompile)):

```
# Extract and prepare the working directories
# -------------------------------------------

mkdir /tmp/tmp/
mkdir /tmp/tmp/extracted/
cp initrd /tmp/tmp/
cd /tmp/tmp
unmkinitramfs initrd ./extracted
cd extracted

# Add the first microcode firmware
# --------------------------------

cd early
find . -print0 | cpio --null --create --format=newc > /tmp/tmp/newinitrd

# Add the second microcode firmware
# ---------------------------------

cd ../early2
find kernel -print0 | cpio --null --create --format=newc >> /tmp/tmp/newinitrd

# Add the ram fs file system
# --------------------------

cd ../main
find . | cpio --create --format=newc | xz --format=lzma >> /tmp/tmp/newinitrd

# Verify both initrds 
# -------------------

cd /tmp/tmp
binwalk initrd
binwalk newinitrd
```

Note that this method is adapted to your situation, on other case where an `initrd` is a `cpio` formatted with `newc` along with `lzma` compression we may use:

```
cd /extracted/initrd
find . | cpio -o -H newc | xz --format=lzma > ../newinitrd
```

Comment: This works as a charm. I have tested, initrd.img (initrd.gz) is a flat concatenation of two cpio archives (each can have different compression). If you merge the two folders: early and main, and create a joint CPIO archive, kernel won't load it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what i use to repack an xz initramfs for syslinux 4.06 (live boot)

```
#!/bin/bash

find . 2>/dev/null | cpio --create --format='newc' > ../initrfs.img.cpio
xz --check=crc32 --lzma2=,dict=2048kiB ../initrfs.img.cpio
mv ../initrfs.img.cpio.xz ../initrfs.img
```

Answer (score 0):

> cpio: option requires an argument -- 'H'

It really needs that `-H newc` option. I tried once without and it did not work. It works without compression.

Comment: I tried many ways.. I think a practical real step by step procedure only the solution. I mean any one successfully made `initrd` recently and successfully booted the live iso. https://superuser.com/q/1556241/976939

Comment: there is no mkinitramfs, besides the unmkinitramfs in Ubuntu? There is no Ubuntu Tag on your Q?

Comment: Ok, If i am not clear when you answered, I am sorry about that. I hope you read the Edited Question few hours ago. Thank You!!!